# Checking the convergence of system of sequences.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\{u_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\{v_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ be the two sequences given by
$$
\begin{cases}
u_0=v_0=1,&\\
u_{k+1}=\left(1-\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\right)u_k+\left(\frac{1}{k+1}\right)v_k, & (k\in \mathbb{N})\\
v_{k+1}=\left(-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)u_k+\left(1-\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\right)v_k. & (k\in \mathbb{N})
\end{cases}
$$
Checking the convergence of the sequences $\{u_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\{v_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: Dear Alex Becker. I tried to do it. I guess that both the sequences are not convergent. Thank you for your consideration of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z_k = u_k + i v_k$.  The recursion says $z_{k+1} = a_{k+1} z_k$, where 
$a_k = 1 - 1/k^2 - i/k$.  Now $a_k = r_k e^{i\theta_k}$ where $r_k = |a_k| = \sqrt{1 - 1/k^2 + 1/k^4}$ and $\theta_k = -\arctan\left(\frac{1/k}{1 - 1/k^2}\right)$.  Thus
$z_n = z_0 \prod_{k=1}^n a_k = \left(\prod_{k=1}^n r_k \right) \exp\left(i \sum_{k=1}^n \theta_k\right)$.

We have $r_k = 1 - 1/(2 k^2) + O(1/k^4)$ and $\theta_k = -1/k + O(1/k^3)$ as $k \to \infty$.  The infinite product $\prod_{k=1}^\infty r_k$ converges to a nonzero limit $R$, so $|z_n| \to R |z_0|$ as $n \to \infty$, but $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \theta_k$ diverges, so $\arg(z_n)$ diverges, and so do the sequences $u_n$ and $v_n$.  In the limit as $n \to \infty$, the points $z_n$ spiral infinitely many times around the circle of radius $R |z_0|$ centred at $0$.

Comment: Thank you Robert Israel for your nice solution. I want to ask you more. If we take a point $\bar{z}$ in the circle of radius $R|z_0|$ centered at $0$, could we choose a subsequence $\{z_{n_i}\}\subset \{z_n\}$ converging to $\bar{z}$.

Comment: Yes, we could do that.

Comment: Dear Robert Israel. Please give your arguments to prove this fact. Thank you.

Comment: I am still confused. Why $\arg(z_n)$ diverges implies both $\{u_n\}$ and $\{v_n\}$ diverge? Let $z_n=u_n+iv_n=r_n(\cos(\theta_n)+i\sin(\theta_n))=r_ne^{i\theta_n}$. Let $r_n=r$ (constant) and $\theta_n=2n\pi$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then $\theta_n$ is not convergent and $u_n=r$, $v_n=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. This means that both $\{u_n\}$ and $\{v_n\}$ are convergent.

Comment: Maybe I should have said $\text{Arg}(z_n)$ (i.e. the version of arg in the interval $(-\pi,\pi]$) diverges.

Comment: As for the question about $\overline{z}$: let $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \theta_k$.  Then as $n \to \infty$, $S_n \to -\infty$ with $\theta_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.  If $N(m)$ is the least $n$ such that $S_n < \text{Arg}(\overline{z}) - 2 \pi m$, then $z_{N(m)} \to \overline{z}$ as $m \to \infty$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2849/discussion-between-impartialmale-and-robert-israel)

Comment: Dear Robert Israel. Could you give more detail why the subsequence $\{z_{N(m)}\}$ converges to $\bar{z}$ as $m\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Sorry, that should have been $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \theta_k$.
The point is that $S_{N(m)} < \text{Arg}(\overline{z}) - 2 \pi m \le S_{N(m)-1}$ and $|S_{N(m)} - S_{N(m)-1}| = |\theta_{N(m)}| \to 0$, so $S_{N(m)} - \text{Arg}(\overline{z}) + 2 \pi m \to 0$,
and thus $e^{iS_{N(m)}} e^{-i \text{Arg}(\overline{z})} \to 1$,
as $m \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you Robert Israel. Your solution is really interesting. It makes me satisfy. Thank you again for your patience to discuss with me.